# Excel 365 - Getting Data Table w/ Images from Web

Tags: excel, vba, image, web-scraping, powerquery

I am using Office 365 and I am trying to get a data table from the web and import it in an Excel sheet together with the images. Here is the table which I am trying to import:

https://royaleapi.com/clan/90R9VPP9/war/analytics

[http://i63.tinypic.com/2s655kx.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/js4AW.jpg)

As you can see from the table, there are images in cells representing certain statuses which contain meaningful data:

- Medal = win
- Cross = loss
- Empty medal slot = missing in action
- Empty cell = didn't participate

I click on data and select From Web, where I paste the link. Excel brings up the following, where I select Table 0 for the info I need.

[http://i67.tinypic.com/2lmb4u0.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Cyw8.jpg)

After I click load, the generated table is as below. As you can see, there are no images which denote the status of the person, this method only gets the texts etc. but the cells which should have contained the images are not pulled.

[http://i67.tinypic.com/n3kzz5.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eaPNJ.jpg)

After searching online, I've managed to put together a code to isolate the images in another query (Query1) which you can find below. This query gives the images but doesn't place them in cells, I've just managed to get to the images themselves :)

```
let
Source = Table.FromColumns({Lines.FromBinary(Web.Contents("https://royaleapi.com/clan/8P2V9VYL/war/analytics"), null, null, 65001)}),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.Contains([Column1], "src=""/static/img/ui")),
#"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Column1", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"src=""/"}, QuoteStyle.None, true), {"Column1.1", "Column1.2"}),
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Column1.1", type text}, {"Column1.2", type text}}),
#"Split Column by Delimiter1" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Changed Type", "Column1.2", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({""""}, QuoteStyle.None, false), {"Column1.2.1", "Column1.2.2"}),
#"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter1",{{"Column1.2.1", type text}, {"Column1.2.2", type text}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Column1.1", "Column1.2.2"}),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "https", each "https://royaleapi.com/"),
#"Reordered Columns" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Added Custom",{"https", "Column1.2.1"}),
#"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Reordered Columns",{"https", "Column1.2.1"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
#"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Merged Columns",{{"Merged", "Images"}}),
#"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "Images", "Images - Copy"),
#"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{{"Images - Copy", "ImageURLs"}})
in
#"Renamed Columns1"
```

So, is there any way to simply get the correct images in their correct cells whenever I refresh the table? Unfortunately, I have very limited coding knowledge so I am open to your suggestions and assistance :)

Thanks in advance!
Oandic

Comment: can you add more of your code?

Comment: Is the CSV not sufficient?

Comment: @Kubie actually, this is the only code I've put together via researching online and this only gives me the individual images. Excel automatically creates the code below for the table without the images:
`let
    Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://royaleapi.com/clan/8P2V9VYL/war/analytics")),
    Data = Source{0}[Data]
in
    #"Data"`

Comment: @QHarr csv file might have worked if it wasn't needed to be downloaded every time I wanted to simply refresh the data. For your 2nd comment, I believe it is what I need as I understand the concept but can't code it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This shows how you can gather the links for the images into a 2d array that can be overlaid onto your data range in the sheet as the dimensions (number of rows and number of columns) match. It means you can loop the rows and columns of the array and use them to index into your data range to have the right location to then add your image from the image URL to the cell.

You can use `.Top` and `.Left` to position. Generic outline code given at bottom. You will need to size images appropriately and space rows and columns as well.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim sResponse As String, html As New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", "https://royaleapi.com/clan/90R9VPP9/war/analytics", False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With

    With html
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        Dim hTable As HTMLTable
        Set hTable = .getElementsByTagName("table")(0)
    End With
    Dim numRows As Long, numColumns As Long, r As Long, c As Long, tr As Object, td As Object

    numRows = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length
    numColumns = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")(2).getElementsByTagName("td").Length
    Dim arr()
    ReDim arr(1 To numRows, 1 To numColumns)

    For Each tr In hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
        r = r + 1: c = 0
        For Each td In tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
            c = c + 1
            arr(r, c) = GetImgLink(td.outerHTML)
        Next
    Next
    [A1].Resize(numRows, numColumns) = arr '<== Just for example to see how would map to sheet
    Stop
End Sub

Public Function GetImgLink(ByVal outerHTML As String) As String
    On Error GoTo Errhand
    GetImgLink = "https://royaleapi.com/" & Split(Split(outerHTML, "IMG class=""ui image"" src=""about:")(1), Chr$(34))(0)
    Exit Function
Errhand:
    Err.Clear
    GetImgLink = vbNullString
End Function
```

---

Adding images and positioning (assuming data starts in A1 otherwise add an adjustment to the row, column indices of the link array you are looping.)

```
With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(imageURL)  ' <== Change to your sheet
    .Left = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Left '<== row and column argument to cells will come from loop position within array. Adjust if required.
    .Top = ActiveSheet.Cells(1,1).Top
    .Placement = 1
End With
```

---

**Sample of how links map to sheet:**

[image: data]

Comment: Thank you very much and so sorry for the late response! This has worked miracles as it made me learn a lot of VBA with additional research, so thank you!! :) @Qharr my only question left is, sometimes there are two images in the original table, but the code only gets the link for one of the images and moves on to the next cell. Is it possible to get both links in the same cell if its two visuals in the original table? Thanks so much again and again!

Comment: Like .:JOSHUA:. 9.23?

Comment: Exactly like JOSHUA in 9.27 and 9.23; two images/links in a single cell?

Comment: I will have a look tomorrow if that is ok? It's gonna be a bit more complex to code.

Comment: I wouldn't call it urgent in any way, so please take your time. I am learning through your codes so willing to wait for it :) And I can't thank you enough!